# Image glare suppression in R (or Python)

Tags: python, r, image-processing

I have photos of metallic part that I would like to analyse in R. Unfortunately, there is bright area (glare) as illustrated below (on top left corner for this example): https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK9mq.jpg

I tried by tuning the contrast and brittleness but with no success.

What would be the best/easiest way to remove or reduce the glare in R (or Python)?

[image]

Comment: *"I tried by tuning the contrast and brittleness but with no success"*, can you please share your trial in terms of code? [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I used the following code but I cannot change locally, it is a global on the picture. I would like to change locally:
  test <-
  raster::stretch(RasterStack,
                  minq = .02,
                  maxq = .98
  )
raster::plotRGB(test)